# How to implement a Image Gallery for a Visualforce Page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, images

I'm searching for a way to implement a Image Gallery for a Visualforce Page.

The Image Gallery have to bind to an List<> Obj where are custom Image Objs contained. This custom Image Objs have a Property called *ImageUrl*.

At the Moment i can generate the Images like that:

```
 <apex:outputpanel styleclass="Optpanel1">  
     <apex:repeat value="{!images}" var="i">
            <div id="{!i.Id}">
                <h1>{!i.Id}</h1>
                <apex:image url="{!i.cuttedPictureUrl}" width="100" height="100"/>
            </div>
        </apex:repeat>                              
     </apex:outputpanel>
```

So the Binding etc is not the Problem, it's more to have a Gallery-Control with SF.com Look&Feel.

The Gallery-Control should have a e.g. a Property like selectedIndex, so that the Controller of the VP can figure out the selected Image.

Any Ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: I've not tried to use this, but Blogforce9 has posted a [VF Attachment Slider](http://blogforce9dev-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/ProjectDetail?id=a0290000009KusR) that may be usable complete or provide some inspiration.

Comment: What is a VisualPage?  Is that different from a Visualforce page?

Comment: @Jagular: No, i mean the same thing. Visualforce Page!
Cheers